# Sieve Of Erastothenes BSP C implementation doesn't find all primes

Tags: c, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have a BSP implementation in C for the Sieve Of Erastothenes, see the code below.

When executed with ./bspsieve 2 100 it however gives the following output:

"It took : 0.000045 seconds for proc 0 out of 2.
23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97,"

for ./bspsieve 1 100 it gives the same, i.e:
"./bspsieve 1 100
 It took : 0.000022 seconds for proc 0 out of 1.
23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97,"

For ./bspsieve 8 100 (so using 8 processors) it gives a segmentation fault.
i.e
"./bspsieve 8 100
It took : 0.000146 seconds for proc 0 out of 8.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
This means that my bounds aren't okay I think?

It fails to find the first primes! I can't find my fault (really inexperienced with C). Except this, are there other improvements to my code you guys can suggest? The algorithm doesn't need to be fast, but any improvement in understandability and readability is welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mcbsp.h>


/*
Note: To compile, this file has to be in the same folder as mcbsp.h and you need the 2 following commands:
gcc -Iinclude/ -pthread -c -o bspsieve.o bspsieve.c
gcc -o bspsieve bspsieve.o lib/libmcbsp1.1.0.a -lpthread -lrt

*/

int procs;
int upperbound;
int *primes;

//SPMD function
void bspSieve(){
    bsp_begin(procs);

    int p = bsp_nprocs(); // p = number of procs obtained 
    int s = bsp_pid();  // s = proc number

    float blocksize;    // block size to be used, note last proc has a different size!
    if( s != p-1){
        blocksize = ceil(upperbound/p); 
    } else {
        blocksize = upperbound - (p-1)*ceil(upperbound/p);
    }

    // Initialize start time and end time, set start time to now.   
    double start_time,end_time;
    start_time = bsp_time();

    // Create vector that has block of candidates
    int *blockvector;
    blockvector = (int *)malloc(blocksize*sizeof(int));
    int q;
    for(q = 0; q<blocksize; q++){
        //List contains the integers from s*blocksize till blocksize + s*blocksize
        blockvector[q] = q + s*blocksize;
    } 

    //We neglect the first 2 'primes' in processor 0.
    if(s == 0){
        blockvector[0] = 0;
        blockvector[1] = 0;
    }

    // We are using the block distribution. We assume that n is large enough  to
    // assure that n/p is larger than sqrt(n). This means that we will always find the
    // sieving prime in the first block, and so have to broadcast from the first 
    // processor to the others.
    long sieving_prime;
    int i;
    bsp_push_reg( &sieving_prime,sizeof(long) );
    bsp_sync();

    for(i = 2; i * i < upperbound; i++) {
        //Part 1: if first processor, get the newest sieving prime, broadcast. Search for newest prime starting from i.
        if(s == 0){
            int findPrimeNb;
            for(findPrimeNb = i; findPrimeNb < blocksize; findPrimeNb++) {
                if( blockvector[findPrimeNb] != 0) {
                    sieving_prime  = blockvector[findPrimeNb];
                    //broadcast
                    int procNb;
                    for(procNb = 0; procNb < p; ++procNb){
                        bsp_put(procNb, &sieving_prime,&sieving_prime,0,sizeof(long));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        bsp_sync();

        //Part 2: Sieve using the sieving prime
        int sievingNb;
        for(sievingNb = 0; sievingNb < blocksize; sievingNb++){
            //check if element is multiple of sieving prime, if so, pcross out (put to zero)
            if( blockvector[sievingNb] % sieving_prime == 0){
                blockvector[sievingNb] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    //part 3: get local primes to central area
    int transferNb;
    long transferPrime;
    for(transferNb = 0; transferNb < blocksize; transferNb++){
        transferPrime = blockvector[transferNb];
        primes[transferPrime] = transferPrime;
    }

    // take the end time.
    end_time = bsp_time();

    //Print amount of taken time, only processor 0 has to do this.
    if( s == 0 ){
        printf("It took : %.6lf seconds for proc %d out of %d. \n", end_time-start_time, bsp_pid(), bsp_nprocs());
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    bsp_pop_reg(&sieving_prime);
    bsp_end();
}



int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc != 3) {
        printf( "Usage: %s <proc count> <upper bound> <n", argv[ 0 ] );
        exit(1);
    }
    //retrieve parameters
    procs = atoi( argv[ 1 ] );
    upperbound = atoi( argv[ 2 ] );

    primes = (int *)malloc(upperbound*sizeof(int));

    // init and call parallel part
    bsp_init(bspSieve, argc, argv); 
    bspSieve();

    //Print all non zeros of candidates, these are the primes.
    // Primes only go to p*p <= n
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < upperbound; i++) {
        if(primes[i] > 0) {
            printf("%d, ",primes[i]); 
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the result of `./bspsieve 1 100`?

Comment: have you tried debugging? (or just adding plenty of logging messages...)

Comment: Should've included that, added in the question.

Comment: Your sieve is immensely complicated.

Comment: What is BSP? Searching for mcbsp.h gives "Multi-Channel Buffered Serial Port" which doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Glad you asked! BSP or "Bulk synchronous parallel" is a bridging model for developing parallel algorithms. Kinda comparable to MPI but MPI is an interface, while BSP is a  model. It also helps in making performance assessments. For further information I recommend the book " Parallel Scientific Computation" by prof. Bisseling

Comment: Look, if you're writing anything that involves something as complicated as Parallel Algorithms, you *must* know how to debug.  Basic topics are: starting the debugger, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables and memory, stepping through code.   You cannot reasonably claim to be writing advanced parallel algorithms, yet claim that you don't know how to use a debugger.

Comment: Funny thing that. I have to make a parallel algorithm but it was stated explicitely mulitple times that we don't have to be able to program in C. A little bit of Java background was "more than sufficient". Since I come from a nice protective Java background with an IDE on a windows environment, it is rather difficult to work  on a C algorithm, on a remote computer (did I mention that? It is remotely) using a text editor  on a linux environment. No excuse for my ineptitude, but hopefully it explains somewhat.

Comment: In that case, I don't blame you nearly as much as your Instructor / Professor.  (Hint:  The single most important question I've been asked in my last 3 job interviews was, "How familiar with debuggers are you?" Being able to answer that question alone guaranteed me jobs over other candidates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubles may come from

```
blockvector[q] = q + s*blocksize;
```

As long as `blocksize` is equal to `ceil(upperbound/p)` on all processus, there is no problem. Since 1 and 2 are divisor of 100, your program works well.

As you wrote in your code, it is not always the case...It is not true on the last processus when calling `./bspsieve 8 100`. Some values in blockvector are above 100, and a segmentation fault is likely to appear when writting in the `prime` array.

A way to correct this behaviour is :

```
   blockvector[q] = q + s*ceil(upperbound/p);
```

(store `ceil(...)` to run faster.)

It might also be better to zero the `prime` array before using it.
I did not check wheather it works...Try it !

Bye,

Francis

Answer (score 1):

Some possible issues are noted below. Note that if you had supplied a standalone, compilable example (as an external download for example) it would make it easier for someone unfamiliar with the BSP library to help you. Also noting the specific library would help (assuming it is [MulticoreBSP](http://www.multicorebsp.com/main/library/)).

- I believe you are incorrectly dividing the number by itself. For example try manually tracing the first case:

  - i = 2
  - so sieving_prime = 2
  - 2 % 2 == 0 so blockvector[2] = 0 (incorrectly saying 2 is not prime)
- This issue is why you are only outputting primes starting at 23. You are looping 8 times (`for (i=2; i*i<100...`, 2..9). For these loops you start at the primes 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 which incorrectly eliminates each them leaving 23 as the first prime output.
- For `upperbound/p` when both variables are integers the division result will be an integer so that `ceil(upperbound/p)` probably doesn't do what you think it does. For example `ceil(100/8) == 12` not 13. Cast the numbers to `float` if you wish the division result to be a floating point.
- Related to this your last block is not being populated with numbers correctly when the last block is a different size (i.e., `procs` does not evenly divide `upperbound`). For example in the case of `bspsieve 8 100` your last block starts at ***112*** instead of 90.
- This last issue is most likely the cause of your segmentation fault since a value of 112 will overflow your `primes[]` array.

Fixing these issues 'should' fix the incorrect output and the crash. If you are still getting incorrect output I would add liberal `printf()` calls until you can see where the code differs from what it should be. I would also start testing with 1 processor first and increment this one at a time to confirm correct operation. Also test with different upper bounds.

Comment: You are correct of course. My excuses. At the moment I don't have time but I'll try to include all your suggestions asap (in a couple of hours).

Since the other guy was earlier however, I accept his answer. But, I've upvoted yours!